# ggplot and ggarrange - how to prevent legend box from being cut off?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For me this issue only happens on Mac. Unfortunately I am traveling and I only have my Macbook with me. Here is a minimal example. The problem doesn't appear in individual plots, but only when they are joined via `ggarrange`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))

ggarrange(p1, p2, common.legend = T, legend = "right")
```

Now look at the graph:

[image]

As you can see, the right border of the legend box is cut off. How do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to switch to `patchwork` to glue your plots together:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point()

p1 + p2 +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") &
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with `ggpubr` here is a solution that is admittedly not great but works.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "white", linewidth  = 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth  = 1),
        legend.box.margin = margin(r = 20))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color = "white", linewidth  = 1),
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linewidth  = 1),
        legend.box.margin = margin(r = 20))

ggarrange(p1, p2, common.legend = T, legend = "right")
```

[image]